# dynamic array code keeps crashing

Tags: c

here's a really simple C program, and I just can't figure out why it crashes:

```
int main () {

    size_t argc = 2;
    char **argv = malloc(argc * sizeof(char *));
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        if (i >= argc) {
            argc *= 2;
            argv = realloc(argv, argc);
        }
        argv[i] = strdup("hello world!");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        printf("argv[%d] = \"%s\"\n", i, argv[i]); // it crashes on this line
        free(argv[i]);
    }

    free(argv);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
       argv = realloc(argv, argc);
```

The size is wrong; you want `argc * sizeof(*argv)` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why I missed that. I knew it had to be something really stupid!

Answer (score 3):

When you do your `realloc`, you're allocating space for N chars instead of N pointers to char.

Then again, given that you just want space for 20 items anyway, why not just start by allocating space for 20 items, putting the data there, and being done with it?

```
#define size 20
char **argv = malloc(size * sizeof(char *));
if (argv == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Allocation failed!");
    return 1;
}
for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
    argv[i] = strdup("hello world!");
```

Also note that `realloc` can/will return a null pointer in case of failure, so you generally want to do something like:

```
char **temp = realloc(old_ptr, new_size);
if (temp != NULL)
    old_ptr = temp;
```